# XamlGame<Game>.Create will not accept PhoneApplicationPage (MonoGame 3.0.1)

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, monogame

I trying to start develop a game for Windows Phone 8, but I have got a problem. When I pass PhoneApplicationPage to XamlGame.Create it will not compile. I have read several tutorials when they do that way. This for example,  http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Auto-Scaling_WVGA_XNA_Games_to_WXGA_%26_720P_with_MonoGame_for_WP8

Any one else that hade the same problem?

I downloaded MonoGame 3.0.1 from  http://monogame.net/downloads.

```
public partial class GamePage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private Game1 _game;
    public static GamePage Instance = null;
    // ConstructorT
    public GamePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (Instance != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("An instance is already created");

        Instance = this;

        _game = XamlGame<Game1>.Create("", this);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make two changes here: one to GamePage.xaml and one to GamePage.xaml.cs.  First, go to GamePage.xaml and change

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
```

to

```
<DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
```

That gives you a nice DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid to work with.  Then, go into GamePage.xaml.cs and change

```
_game = XamlGame<Game1>.Create("", this);
```

to

```
_game = XamlGame<Game1>.Create("", this.LayoutRoot);
```

I can't guarantee everything will work perfectly, but by making these changes I at least got my project to build, deploy, and deploy a nice cornflower blue screen (which at least means Game1.Draw works).

Comment: I want to work with DrawingSurface as in the example because it is much easier to work with scaling and orientation. Or do you have any good examples how to work with for example orientation when using DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid?

Comment: I don't, sadly.  I'm also just starting out with MonoGame, and just discovered this a few minutes before I posted it.

Comment: Are your game in landscape or portrait mode?